# Custom Tkinter Widget Won't Pack in Toplevel?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a custom Tkinter widget by subclassing a Frame to make a scrollable widget that contains items. I have 2 windows, my root window and a toplevel window and I need my custom widget to pack to the toplevel window.

My problem is, that despite making 'top' the parent of my custom widget, it still packs in the root window. I've tried other widgets and they pack to the toplevel window fine.

my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="#000000")
root.wm_attributes("-alpha","0.7")

top = Toplevel()
top.config(bg="#000001")
top.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
top.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor","#000001")
top.wm_title("TOPLEVEL")



class Scrollygrid(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns, h, w):
        super(Scrollygrid, self).__init__()
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        self.area = Canvas(self, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, width = w, height = h, bg = "#000001", bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.gridframe = Frame(height = h*10, width = w, bg = "#FF0000")
        self.gridframe.pack_propagate(0)
        self.area.create_window((0, 0), window = self.gridframe)
        for i in range(500):
            Label(self.gridframe, text = i).pack()
        self.area.pack()
        self.area.config(scrollregion = (self.area.bbox("all")))
        self.scrollbar.config(command = self.area.yview)
        def onScroll(event):
            self.area.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/60)), "units")
        self.area.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", onScroll)
        self.scrollbar.pack_forget() #scroll wheel still works!

testgrid = Scrollygrid(top, 1,root.winfo_screenheight()-80,root.winfo_screenwidth()-(root.winfo_screenwidth()/10))
testgrid.pack(side = RIGHT, anchor = CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

the transparent color and alpha level have been left in to make it more immediately obvious which window is which.

Comment: @Nae I'm not sure what you mean. The code above is a very stripped down version of my actual program for clarity. The above code on it's own does indeed produce a GUI.

Comment: My bad, missed the `mainloop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top` isn't the parent of your custom widget. You're never passing it. Your `Scrollygrid` is being passed a `parent` parameter and *that's it*. *Nothing* tells it to assign it as the parent as an attribute even. So the parent *defaults* to the `Tk` instance, `root`.

Replace:

```
super(Scrollygrid, self).__init__()
```

with:

```
super(Scrollygrid, self).__init__(parent)
```

In order to pass the given widget argument as *the* parent to the superclass, `Frame`. Essentially making the `Toplevel`, `top` your custom class' parent. Upon which you'll get further error(s) but the parent is *correctly* assigned. Verify by:

```
print(repr(self.winfo_toplevel()))
```